# MongoDB and Ruby: runCommand geoNear and sorting by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

So I want to do geoNear using runCommand on mongodb and I want the results to be sorted by date.

I know how to do the first part

`db.users.runCommand({'geoNear' :"users",'near' : [-76.483999, 42.402794], 'spherical' : true, 'maxDistance' : 20/6378 })`

but how do i get the results such that it is ordered by created_at? If I were to use Mongo gem to do this, the query would look like

`User.database.command({'geoNear'=>"users",'near' => [-122, 37]}, 'spherical' => true, 'maxDistance' => 20/6378)`

Still, I do not know how to sort it by date. I was considering of using an index on created_at in this case. I have indices on both location and created_at but the results are still not returned by order of created_at date. Does anyone have any clue on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think its possible to add sort to [geonear](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-geoNearCommand) command, as per the link

> Valid options are: "near", "num", "maxDistance", "distanceMultiplier"
>   and "query".

by default it sorted by the distance.

Alternatively you can write your spherical query like this

```
db.users.find( { loc :  { $nearSphere : [80.21223299999997, 13.034892],$maxDistance:20/6378  } } ).sort({ created_at : -1 } ) //-1 for descending
```

your ruby mongomapper equivalent might be (not sure, better verify)

```
Users.where(:loc => {'$nearSphere' => [-122, 37],'$maxDistance'=>20/6378 }).sort(:created_at.desc)
```